# WCF Client : The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, forms-authentication

Hi I am using WCF with CustomUserNameValidator, i am using visual studio local iis,

---------- WCF application--

```
namespace AuthenticateWCF
{
    public class CustomUserNameValidator : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator
    {

        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName == null && password == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            if (!(userName == "rrr" && password == "ppp"))
                throw new FaultException("incorrect password");


        }
    }
}
```

my webconfig file:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
             customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="AuthenticateWCF.CustomUserNameValidator, AuthenticateWCF"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBasic">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="wsHttp">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"  />
          </security>
      </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

when calling this service in my test project,

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client _client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "a";
_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "bb";
var result = _client.GetData(5);
```

client web config file, here i am using TransportWithMessageCredential, to validate username

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" >
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
    </security>
</binding>
```

but when i use this i am getting error

> he provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.

I know we can change security mode, but if i change this will not authenticate user.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you using TransportWithMessageCredential security mode I assume your are consuming your service over https.
Secondly you either remove following configuration.

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Or change it to

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Comment: Under Configuration Tag?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale : Under <system.serviceModel>.

Comment: Getting unauthorized exception

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347576/how-to-call-webservice-in-webapi-project