# The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized while calling web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have URL of web service and I am trying to call that web service in my WebAPI project.

URL: `http://domain/soap/wsdl11?services=XYZ_Service&sap-client=007&sap-user=demo&sap-password=demo@123`

The code that I have tried:

```
Service.DemoService client = new Service.DemoService();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("demo", "demo@123", "domain");
client.PreAuthenticate = true;
client.GetData("Test");
```

But its showing:

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

The above URL is working in the browser.

Comment: Are you sure that provided network credentials are correct?

Comment: Yes while hitting this url on the browser the XML details is getting displayed

Answer (score 1):

You can use service reference in you application.
Right click references click to Add Service Reference popup will appear where you can add your web service URL(without method and parameters) by give the service reference with name.
It will behave as normal dll or any other reference.
create instance of service reference name then use the instance to call which ever method from your web service with parameters if parameters exist.

Comment: Exactly followed the same process but getting unauthorized

Comment: The web service which you are consuming is in same domain or different domain.

Comment: Different domain

Comment: If it is in different domain checkout that they have handled proper cross-origins(CORS). Or is there any thing you need to add in header of your service call.